# How to add an ORDER BY clause using CodeIgniter's Active Record methods?

Tags: php, codeigniter, select, activerecord, sql-order-by

I have a very small script to get all records from a database table, the code is below.

```
$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
return $query->result();
```

Using this syntax, how would I add a `ORDER BY 'name'` clause to my select query?

I get errors every time I stick the order by bit on the end.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

I believe the `get()` function immediately runs the select query and does not accept `ORDER BY` conditions as parameters. I think you'll need to separately declare the conditions, then run the query. Give this a try:

```
$this->db->from($this->table_name);
$this->db->order_by("name", "asc");
$query = $this->db->get(); 
return $query->result();
```

[CodeIgniter Documentation `order_by()`](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#:%7E:text=%24this%2D%3Edb%2D%3Eorder_by(),are%20ASC%2C%20DESC%20AND%20RANDOM.)

Answer (score 19):

Using this code to multiple order by in single query.

```
$this->db->from($this->table_name);
$this->db->order_by("column1 asc,column2 desc");
$query = $this->db->get(); 
return $query->result();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to a different question.  Ted already adequately answered the question asked back in 2011.

Answer (score 4):

Simple and easy:

```
$this->db->order_by("name", "asc");
$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
return $query->result();
```

Comment: Yes, this is "_simple and easy_".  Probably as simple as reading the top-voted and accepted answer on this page which was posted back in 2011.  Please 1. never post code-only answers and 2. only post an answer if you have something unique and valuable to add to the page.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the'order_by' clause to your code and modify it to look just like the one below.

```
$this->db->order_by('name', 'asc');
$result = $this->db->get($table);
```

There you go.

Comment: `where` must come before `order_by`

Comment: @SaniKamal Yes, in sql, WHERE must come before ORDER BY, but when making Active Record method calls, CodeIgniter will automatically organize the rendered query clauses in the correct order.

Comment: @Obi The recommendation to use `order_by()` was already given by the top voted and accepted answer on this page.  Therefore, this answer provides no new value to the page.  Please only post new answers on Stack Overflow when you have something unique and  valuable to express regarding the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getProductionGroupItems($itemId){
     $this->db->select("*");
     $this->db->where("id",$itemId);
     $this->db->or_where("parent_item_id",$itemId);

    /*********** order by *********** */
     $this->db->order_by("id", "asc");

     $q=$this->db->get("recipe_products");
     if($q->num_rows()>0){
         foreach($q->result() as $row){
             $data[]=$row;
         }
         return $data;
     }
    return false;
}
```