# Codeigniter order_by name not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I am pulling 10 records from database at the time using AJAX call.

below is my code:

```
public function get_next_10($offset = 0)
{
    $this->db->limit(15, $offset);
    $query = $this->db->get("postovi");
    return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->result_array() : NULL;
}
```

I tried putting:

```
$this->db->order_by("name", "asc");
```

but it's throwing an error.

Comment: What language is that ? o.O

Comment: The language is PHP

Comment: It breaks? What is the error message?

Comment: check this answer in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320395/codeigniter-order-by-on-a-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its Working Fine

```
public function get_next_10($offset = 0)
{
$this->db->limit(15, $offset);
$this->db->order_by('name', 'asc');
$query = $this->db->get("postovi");
return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->result_array() : NULL;
}
```