# ORDER BY In Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function mandarin_2($limit = '', $offset = '')
    {
        $data['aktivisdcm1'] = $this->db->get_where('tb_imam', array('status' => 'Aktivis'))->result_array();

    $data['title'] = 'Absensi Mandarin 2';
    $this->load->view('absensi/mandarin_2', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    // $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

please help .. how do I make an order by my coding? thank you, I really hope the response

Comment: simply using `$this->db->order_by("field", "asc");`

Comment: Like This?

$data['aktivisdcm1'] = $this->db->order_by("nama", "asc") get_where('tb_imam', array('status' => 'Aktivis'))->result_array();

Comment: you should specify on which field you want to sort.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CodeIgniter - ORDER BY on a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320395/codeigniter-order-by-on-a-query)

Comment: Like this : `$data['aktivisdcm1'] = $this->db->order_by("nama", "asc")-> get_where('tb_imam', array('status' => 'Aktivis'))->result_array();`

Comment: SOLVED..
Thank you verry much...

Answer (score 1):

You can check their documentation right here for their ordering results. This is how they do it.

```
$this->db->order_by('title', 'DESC');
// Produces: ORDER BY `title` DESC
```

[CodeIgniter Documentation Query Builder Class Ordering Results](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=order#ordering-results)

Answer (score 1):

I try this to solve:

```
$data['aktivisdcm1'] = $this->db->order_by("nama", "asc")-> get_where('tb_imam', array('status' => 'Aktivis'))->result_array();
```